# How to open pdf using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, jspdf

I am trying to develop in which the user can upload their `pdf` and add images to it. But i can't  find any resource on how to read a `pdf` file in `nodejs` and open it in `jspdf` to edit it.
Can I open the uploaded `pdf` using `jspdf`?

Comment: Which library are you using ?

Comment: @BasitAnwer I am using jspdf. But i cannot find a way to open an existing pdf using jspdf. Is there any way i can do it?